# What's a lightweight shared memory-based IPC mechanism in C/C++ for Windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, ipc

I've been working on a few C++ projects now which involve doing some simple IPC using window messages. In a number of cases, some extra data is passed with the window messages by putting the data into a shared memory segment and then passing the pointer into the shared memory with the [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950(VS.85).aspx) call. Re-doing this all the time is annoying, but before resolving this dull repetition by inventing yet another IPC system I'd like to ask:

Is there an existing framework which satisfies the criteria?:

- Written in C or C++ (we're using MSVC here)
- As few dependencies as possible; in the best case, it's just a few source files which use plain C++ and Windows standard libraries and which can be compiled directly into the application/library.
- Works on Windows XP and newer
- Is built on window messages plus a shared memory segment
- Proper error reporting would be highly desireable (remote process is gone, remote process doesn't understand given message, argument mismatch, etc.)

For what it's worth, COM is not really an option for us since it's so painful to work with it (unless you start using all kinds of wrappers on top of it which we'd like to avoid). I don't really need interfaces and all that stuff; just a convenient way to send messages with (in the best case arbitrary) arguments back and forth with a bit of error handling. Also, I discarded DBUS for doing so much more than I need.

Comment: I don't see why COM is painful to work with, particularly when you have ATL at your disposal (as you do on MSVC++).

Comment: @Billy ONeal: ATL is one of the frameworks on top of COM which I was thinking of when writing `unless you start using all kinds of wrappers on top of it which we'd like to avoid`.

Comment: @French: Err.. my point was that **you** don't have to write any kind of wrapper. It's already written for you.

Comment: *"Is built on window messages plus a shared memory segment"* - That's an odd criteria. Why does a solution need to exhibit a particular implementation detail? An extremely simple solution can be built around [SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx), [WM_COPYDATA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011.aspx), and serialization (see [Using Data Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649009.aspx)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although does not meet all of your criteria, [ZeroMQ (http://www.zeromq.org/)](http://www.zeromq.org) might be worth looking at. It is small, simple and fast. Also it gives you message passing semantics which may help depending on the type of applications you are using

Comment: +1: Never heard of this before, thanks for making me aware of it; looking at it.

Comment: It's very lightweight. I haven't used it myself but I'm considering taking a look next time I need some IPC.

Comment: IPC is not implemented in zmq for Windows

Answer (score 3):

I've had success using a memory mapped file for interprocess communication.  I like it mainly because it's simple, fast, and available on any version of windows you're likely to come across (well, i doubt it will work on Win9x, but....)

There's a basic article at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx (writtin in 1993!) that shows how to use them.

Comment: +1: Interesting - this looks pretty good. It'd be even sweeter if there was some slim C++ library built around it. :-)

Comment: I'm still looking for one.

Answer (score 2):

This question is almost 3 years old at the time of this answer, but I can't believe nobody has formally suggested [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/interprocess.html).

Light-weight, IPC, and C++ wrappings for WINAPI mechanisms are available.